# View not laid out properly when keyboard is hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitextview, autolayout

I have a `TextView`. When keyboard appears, part of the `TextView` is hidden behind keyboard. So, I decrease its height by decreasing its bottom constraint(with its superview's bottom) so that user can scroll and see whole text.

But issue is when keyboard disappears its not resizing `TextView`'s height to original. But when I tap on it, it shows whole text same as in first image.

**How it looks normally :**

[image]

**How it looks when keyboard has appeared :**

[image]

**How it looks when keyboard has disappeared :**

[image]

**Now, if I tap on `TextView` it looks same as first image. i.e. resizes to have proper size :**

[image]

**Code :** `self.messageView` is `TextView`.

```
// Called when keyboard is going to be displayed
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];

    // get animation info from userInfo
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    CGRect keyboardFrame;
    [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
    [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardFrame];

    // Save constant to set back later
    self.bottomConstant = self.noticeMessageBottom.constant;

    // Change bottom space constraint's constant
    self.noticeMessageBottom.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height + 8.0f;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

        [self.messageView setNeedsLayout];
        [self.messageView layoutIfNeeded];

        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:nil];

    [self.messageView flashScrollIndicators];
}

// Called when keyboard is going to be hidden
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];

    // get animation info from userInfo
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    CGRect keyboardFrame;
    [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
    [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardFrame];

    // Reset contentOffset
    self.messageView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;

    // Change bottom space constraint's constant
    self.noticeMessageBottom.constant = self.bottomConstant;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

        [self.messageView setNeedsLayout];
        [self.messageView layoutIfNeeded];

        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

**Update :** I set background color to `TextView` and saw that height is changed properly but part of the text is not visible. It becomes visible when I tap on it.

[image]

***Note :*** This happens only if `TextView`'s `contentOffset` is `(0,0)`.i.e user has not scrolled it. If user has scrolled it and `contentOffset` is not `(0,0)` then it works fine.

Comment: What's the result of this line: self.bottomConstant = self.view.bounds.size.height - (self.messageView.frame.origin.y + self.messageView.bounds.size.height); ?

Comment: @LordZsolt Just saving current value of constant. Edited question to make it more clear. Check it now.

Comment: I know it's saving the current value of the constant... duh... I want to know the numeric value...

Comment: why not using scrollView?

Comment: @iBug `TextView` is subclass of `scrollview`. It has scroll indicators.

Comment: I know it does. I was saying about putting textView in scrollView. And setting contentOffSet for scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

I just unchecked scroll enabled property of `TextView` in storyboard and its not giving that issue any more.

[image]